# Substrate - Pallet-Nicks Tutorial - error: unexpected token #10993

Tags: rust, substrate

added dependencies & features in the Cargo.toml
then: $ cargo build --release

how can I fix this?

A lot of errors are occurring:

```
Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/robert/substrate-node-template/runtime)
   Compiling pallet-nicks v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.17#22d40c76)
error: failed to run custom build command for `node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/robert/substrate-node-template/runtime)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `/home/robert/substrate-node-template/target/release/build/node-template-runtime-6e84ec0a3716120c/build-script-build` (exit status: 1)
  --- stdout
  Information that should be included in a bug report.
  Executing build command: "rustup" "run" "nightly" "cargo" "rustc" "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown" "--manifest-path=/home/robert/substrate-node-template/target/release/wbuild/node-template-runtime/Cargo.toml" "--color=always" "--profile" "release"
  Using rustc version: rustc 1.61.0-nightly (38a0b81b1 2022-03-06)


  --- stderr
     Compiling pallet-nicks v4.0.0-dev (https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git?branch=polkadot-v0.9.17#22d40c76)
     Compiling node-template-runtime v4.0.0-dev (/home/robert/substrate-node-template/runtime)
  error: unexpected token
     --> /home/robert/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:326:2
      |
  326 | /     {
  327 | |         /* --snip-- */
  328 | |         Balances: pallet_balances,
  329 | |
  330 | |         /*** Add This Line ***/
  331 | |         Nicks: pallet_nicks,
  332 | |     }
      | |_____^

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Runtime`
     --> /home/robert/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:396:24
      |
  396 |             OpaqueMetadata::new(Runtime::metadata().into())
      |                                 ^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type `Runtime`

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Aura`
     --> /home/robert/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:439:49
      |
  439 |             sp_consensus_aura::SlotDuration::from_millis(Aura::slot_duration())
      |                                                          ^^^^ use of undeclared type `Aura`

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Aura`
     --> /home/robert/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:443:4
      |
  443 |             Aura::authorities().into_inner()
      |             ^^^^ use of undeclared type `Aura`

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Grandpa`
     --> /home/robert/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:461:4
      |
  461 |             Grandpa::grandpa_authorities()
      |             ^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type `Grandpa`

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `Grandpa`
     --> /home/robert/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:465:4
      |
  465 |             Grandpa::current_set_id()
      |             ^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type `Grandpa`

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `System`
     --> /home/robert/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:491:4
      |
  491 |             System::account_nonce(account)
      |             ^^^^^^ use of undeclared type `System`

  error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared type `TransactionPayment`
     --> /home/robert/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:500:4
      |
  500 |             TransactionPayment::query_info(uxt, len)
      |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ use of undeclared type `TransactionPayment`
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

When you get this type of chained errors, it is likely that you have copied something wrong, accidentally deleting some important element, for example, a comma, a semicolon, etc.

Make sure you didn't delete anything important and try again.
If this is not the case, then check this line, I think it is the key:

```
error: unexpected token --> /home/robert/substrate-node-template/runtime/src/lib.rs:326:2 
| 326 | / { 327 | | /* --snip-- / 328 | | Balances: pallet_balances, 329 
| 
| 330 | | /** Add This Line ***/ 331 | | Nicks: pallet_nicks, 332 | | } 
| |_____^
```